# history e preventDefault se anulando!

Tags: javascript, react

Então galera o problema é o seguinte eu pego alguns dados vou no banco de dados e verifico se a pessoa pode se autentificar, porém eu uso o `preventDefault()` para a pagina não atualizar e o dados não se perderem, o meu problema é: parece que o `history` não consegue carregar a pagina com o `preventDefault` e se eu tirar eu perco os dados, queria saber se tem alguma solução para isso. ou vou ter que usar alguma estrategia diferente.

```js
export default function LoginCard() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('digite seu email')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('digite seu password')


  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await api.post('/autentication', {
        email,
        password
      })
    } catch (error) {
      return console.log("error", error)
    }
    history.push('/areadoaluno')
  }



  return ( <
    ContainerLogin >

    <
    LoginMenu >
    <
    ContainerImg >
    <
    img src = "https://i.imgur.com/Aaeevvn.png"
    alt = "logo-sieve" / >
    <
    /ContainerImg> <
    Formulario >
    <
    form onSubmit = {
      handleSubmit
    } >
    <
    Inputs >
    <
    GoPerson size = "28px" / > < input value = {
      email
    }
    onChange = {
      e => setEmail(e.target.value)
    }
    type = "email"
    name = "email" / >
    <
    /Inputs> <
    br / >
    <
    br / >
    <
    Inputs >
    <
    FaLock size = "28px" / > < input value = {
      password
    }
    onChange = {
      e => setPassword(e.target.value)
    }
    type = "password"
    name = "password" / >
    <
    /Inputs> <
    br / >
    <
    div >
    <
    a href = "www.google.com.br" > Esqueceu sua senha ? < /a> <
    /div> <
    br / >
    <
    div >
    <
    input type = "checkbox"
    name = "check" / > < span > Mantenha - me conectado < /span> <
    /div> <
    br / >
    <
    br / >
    <
    Realysub >
    <
    button className = "Login"
    type = "submit" > Login < /button> <
    Link to = "/form" > < button className = "Register" > Cadastro < /button></Link >
    <
    /Realysub> <
    /form> <
    /Formulario> <
    /LoginMenu> <
    /ContainerLogin>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O event.preventDefault e o history não tem conflito entre eles, percebi que você esta utilizando o ReactHooks, para utilizar o **history.push({rota})**, você precisa fazer a chamada da função dele conforme a documentação: [Documentação history push](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory).

Você deve:

1. Importar o useHistory: `import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";`
2. Atribuir essa função em uma variável chamada history: `const history = useHistory();`

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"; // Importar o useHistory

export default function LoginCard() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('digite seu email')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('digite seu password')
  
  const history = useHistory(); // Fazer a chamada da função history

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await api.post('/autentication', {
        email,
        password
      })
    } catch (error) {
      return console.log("error", error)
    }
    history.push('/areadoaluno')
  }



  return ( <
    ContainerLogin >

    <
    LoginMenu >
    <
    ContainerImg >
    <
    img src = "https://i.imgur.com/Aaeevvn.png"
    alt = "logo-sieve" / >
    <
    /ContainerImg> <
    Formulario >
    <
    form onSubmit = {
      handleSubmit
    } >
    <
    Inputs >
    <
    GoPerson size = "28px" / > < input value = {
      email
    }
    onChange = {
      e => setEmail(e.target.value)
    }
    type = "email"
    name = "email" / >
    <
    /Inputs> <
    br / >
    <
    br / >
    <
    Inputs >
    <
    FaLock size = "28px" / > < input value = {
      password
    }
    onChange = {
      e => setPassword(e.target.value)
    }
    type = "password"
    name = "password" / >
    <
    /Inputs> <
    br / >
    <
    div >
    <
    a href = "www.google.com.br" > Esqueceu sua senha ? < /a> <
    /div> <
    br / >
    <
    div >
    <
    input type = "checkbox"
    name = "check" / > < span > Mantenha - me conectado < /span> <
    /div> <
    br / >
    <
    br / >
    <
    Realysub >
    <
    button className = "Login"
    type = "submit" > Login < /button> <
    Link to = "/form" > < button className = "Register" > Cadastro < /button></Link >
    <
    /Realysub> <
    /form> <
    /Formulario> <
    /LoginMenu> <
    /ContainerLogin>

  );
}
```